# How to display an "alert" for an option to "selected" with a click using jquery and "ID"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, click

I have the following code in my **html >  body:**

```
<select class="btntabla" id="opciones" style="height: 32px;">
    <option selected id="mostrartodo"       >Mostrar todo</option>
    <option          id="mostrargrafica"    >Mostrar solo gráfica</option>
    <option          id="mostrartabulacion" >Mostrar solo tabulación</option>
    <option          id="solografica"       >Ocultar solo gráfica</option>
    <option          id="solotabulacion"    >Ocultar solo tabulación</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying with jquery something like this in my **html > head:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $("#mostrartodo").click(function() {
          alert("hola");
    });
</script>
```

I want to give you click on a **"option"** of **"select"** display an **"alert"**

> How I can do that?

Comment: have you included the jQuery? Please see http://jsfiddle.net/2GUh8/2/ it is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to the change event on your `select`:

```
$('#opciones').on('change', function (event) {
    // Will always be triggered when the select changes ...
    alert('hola');
    // .. so you should check for the value
    // (please add some value attribute to your options)
    if ($(this).find('option:selected').val() === '1') {
      alert('HOLA');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#opciones").on('change',function() {
       alert($(this).find("option:selected").text()+' clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...
this is not a correct way to do...

```
$("#opciones").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).text(); 
    if (value == 'Mostrar todo'){
   alert('hola');
}
});
```

Hope this will work...